# Getting thumbnail link of a bitstream in dspace using solr query

Tags: xml, xslt, solr, dspace

Does anyone know how to get a bitstream thumbnail Url using solr query.

I am trying to make a Gallery using bit stream thumbnails in homepage of our dspace repository.

I am using this solr query get the items as follows.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('http://localhost:8080/solr/search/select?q=search.resourcetype:2&amp;sort=dc.date.accessioned_dt%20desc&amp;rows=1&amp;fl=dc.date.accessioned_dt&amp;omitHeader=true'))"
mode="solr-response"/>
```

Which result in this xml file

```
</arr>
<arr name="dc.type.en_US">
<str>Book</str>
</arr>
<arr name="dc.identifier.uri">
<str>http://localhost:8080/xmlui/handle/123456789/118</str>
</arr>
<date name="dc.date.accessioned_dt">2017-06-13T03:40:50Z</date>
<arr name="dc.date.accessioned">
<str>2017-06-13T03:40:50Z</str>
</arr>
<arr name="dc.date.available">
<str>2017-06-13T03:40:50Z</str>
</arr>
```

With the above xml file, I can access the url of an item, but how to get the URL of the Thumbnail of these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitstream URL's are not available in the SOLR repository in the current versions of DSpace.

You could use the DSpace REST API to retrieve this information: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API

If you run XMLUI, you can pull bitstream information as XML with the following URL pattern.  Here is an example from the demo.dspace.org site.  Note that no thumbnails are currently available on the demo site, but the following call would reveal them.

- Item: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/handle/10673/10
- Bitstream info: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/metadata/handle/10673/10/mets.xml?rightsMDTypes=METSRIGHTS

Comment: Thankyou @terrywb for your answer, I think using REST will be a solution for me. Sadly I found that there is no searching features implemented in DSpace REST API.

Comment: @shining, The DSpace 6 REST api has some metadata query features, but it does not have full text search capabilities.  See https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+Based+Quality+Control+Reports